# loading a shapefile with properties in non-UTF8 formats

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, leaflet

I can successfully load and display a shapefile in Leaflet. However, when I try to access the features properties, the characters are all mangled. To investigate, I defined the following function:

```
function unpack(str) {
    var codePoints = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        codePoints.push( str.charCodeAt(i) );
    return codePoints;
};
```

Then, I do the following:

```
const options = {
    onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
         console.log(unpack(feature.properties.NAME));
    }
};
L.shapefile(url, options);
```

When I load the application I see on the console arrays like the following:

> [65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 65533]

... which corresponds to the [Unicode replacement character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

For what it's worth, I've examined the *.dbf file using a binary editor and I've established that the `feature.properties.NAME` is given in ISO 8859-7 (ISO Latin/Greek alphabet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a trip down the rabbit hole of how [Leaflet.shapefile](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) handles strings from features' properties.

First off, if you know a bit about the [shapefile format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile), you'll be familiar with the fact that the `.shp` file holds the geometries and that the `.dbf` file holds the properties. The data for each feature is split between those files.

So Leaflet.shapefile depends on [shapefilejs](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js) to do the parsing, and in turn shapefilejs depends on [parseDBF](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/parseDBF) to read the contents of the `.dbf` file. Reading a [bit of the code from parseDBF](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/parseDBF/blob/4f7820e2dacd388f678d08e4b79f9077ad6c56ce/index.js#L65-L66) shows that there's support for multiple character encodings via [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite):

```
module.exports = function(buffer, encoding) {
  var decoder = createDecoder(encoding);
  // ...etc...
```

So one can call the `parseDBF` module with a `buffer` for the contents of the DBF file, and pass a string with an iconv-compatible encoding.

Now, does shapefilejs use this functionality? Once again let's [look at the code](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js/blob/8560d2626ad10a70a0e5efea1006bd411f36c5b6/lib/index.js#L96):

```
  if (zip[name + '.dbf']) {
    dbf = parseDbf(zip[name + '.dbf'], zip[name + '.cpg']);
  }
```

This means "if there's a `.dbf` file, call `parseDBF` with the contents of the `.dbf` file and the contents of the `.cpg` file". Wait, why is it reading a `.cpg` file? What does that mean? The answer is in any list of shapefile sidecar files, such as [the one in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile):

> `.cpg` — used to specify the code page (only for .dbf) for identifying the character encoding to be used

This should show that leaflet-shapefile is handling character encoding as expected - it reads encoding information from the right sidecar file, and decodes strings from the `.dbf` file via `iconv-lite`. You should check if that sidecar file exists, and that the contents of that file are the desired character encoding.

Note that [the list of supported encodings for iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Supported-Encodings) (and also [the supported encodings for iconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv)) is far for complete (compared to the [list of known text encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)). Maybe your `.cpg` file is OK but support for that text encoding is just not there.

Comment: There was no *.cpg file so I created one and added a single line "UTF-8859-7" (also tried "1253"). No luck, which makes sense I guess, since this encoding is not listed among those that `iconv-lite` supports. I am accepting this answer even though I obviously wasn't able to confirm the solution.

Comment: I think `iconv-lite` only supports ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-16 whereas `iconv` supports all ISO-8859-* encodings. I'd try hacking `node_modules/parseDBF/decoder.js`, switch that to `iconv` (plus `npm install iconv`), then re-bundle everything.